# Access denied when phpMyAdmin opened using xampp

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

When I use phpMyAdmin under tools, it gives me this error `Connection for control user as defined in your configuration failed.`. I tried some methods like adding `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';` to the config file but it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The disclaimer is that I'm not familiar with XAMPP and how they package phpMyAdmin, but they should have either created a controluser for you or not tried to configure one. It's possible one exists and the password got lost; in theory you should be able to reset the password on the controluser account from within phpMyAdmin.

That being said, unless you plan to use some of the [advanced features](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/pmadb) such as bookmarking or tracking changes, there's rarely a need for a controluser. You can edit your config.inc.php and remove the lines `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser']` and `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass']`. That should eliminate the error message.